# How to uninstall Passenger (mod_rails) from nginx?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger, mod-rails

I've a running nginx and Ubuntu 8.09 site running a rails app -- but we are not making use of Peassenger anymore and it seems to take up a lot of memory.

I google around and there's tons of info on how to install Passenger, but I didn't find any on uninstalling.

Comment: Perhaps "[Uninstalling](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#uninstalling)" would help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IF your only concern is the memory usage, removing the Passenger lines from the webserver config file will cause it to no longer be loaded.

If you want to completely remove it from your system, them you'll have to uninstall the gem too, assuming that's how you initially got it.

*A tip for the future*: I generally keep lots of tiny config files, one for each module that I'm using, so that it's easy to find, edit, and eventually, remove them. This is not the general case, though.

**edit**: hum, apparently Passenger compiles a new nginx with support for it, so it's not as simple as removing a module. Well, in that case I'd recommend you wipe your current nginx binary and compile a new one without mod_rails. Notice there may still be lines in the existing config file to be removed.

Comment: This is the problem I am facing -- remocing config lines and reversing installation steps I have done doesn't solve the problem, infact I get weird errors related to Passenger by doing that.

Comment: What errors? If you remove the Phusion Passenger config lines then it's supposed to disable itself.

Comment: The Passenger documentation covers uninstalling. Removing the configuration lines from the config will remove nginx's knowledge of Passenger. The customizing Passenger does for nginx just adds knowledge of what to do with those lines.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your `httpd.conf` and remove the lines you once added to install `mod_rails`.

If you don't remember, look at the *installation* tutorials and undo the steps in reverse order.